# How can I prevent an information to be null?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm doing an map with React Leaflet, and I need the mapRef data to use the 'map' properties. But everytime the page loads, the mapRef is null, and I can't use the map.on.
Is there any way to wait for the mapRef content before the map.on is called?

```
const MapView = () => {

    const mapRef = useRef()

    useEffect(() => {
        const map = mapRef.current

        map.on('click', function(e) {
            console.log(e.latlng)
        })

        console.log(map)

    }, [mapRef])

   return(
        <div>
            <MapContainer 
                ref={mapRef}
                center={coord} 
                zoom={6} 
                scrollWheelZoom={true}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                    
                />
            </MapContainer>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You should add a `onClick` prop to the wrapping `div`, instead of a ref.

Comment: yes, initially any ref object is null. You could just add a validation that if the object is not null then do whatever logic you wish it to do. meaning it wont break at first when its null and work fine after. But in this simple onClick case - do was sean-7777 said. You shouldint go a complex way adding a onclick via useEffect. thats hella overkill. just add onClick to a div element.